# How do I disconnect all bluetooth devices via command line?

Tags: bluetooth, windows-10

When a specific user logs in on Windows 10, I want to have all Bluetooth devices that are currently connected to be disconnected. How would I do this? I want to be able to automatically enter something in the command line either through the task scheduler, or python. I tried installing Bluetooth command-line tools from bluetoothinstaller.com, but the only thing that I can find that works is to do `btpair -u`, but that unpairs all the devices instead of disconnecting them.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to toggle the Bluetooth Off and On.
Its not a proper way to disconnect but it works. Try [RadioControlCmd](https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9PJBRHTBVNMR)! after installing use the following commands  to toggle Bluetooth On and Off

---

*radiocontrol.exe Bluetooth On*

---

*radiocontrol.exe Bluetooth off*